# python numpy array convert to xml

Tags: python, xml, numpy, xml.etree

For example ,there is my data :

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[ 26.2, 280. ],
       [ 26.2, 279. ],
       [ 26. , 278.8],
       [ 25.2, 278. ],
       [ 25. , 277.8],
       [ 24.2, 277. ],
       [ 24. , 276.8],
       [ 23. , 276.8],
       [ 22.8, 277. ],
       [ 23. , 277.2],
       [ 23.8, 278. ],
       [ 24. , 278.2],
       [ 24.8, 279. ],
       [ 25. , 279.2],
       [ 25.8, 280. ],
       [ 26. , 280.2],
       [ 26.2, 280. ]])
```

I want to get a xml flie like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ASAP_Annotations>
    <Annotations>
        <Annotation Name="Annotation 0" Type="Spline" PartOfGroup="_1" Color="#F4FA58">
            <Coordinates>
                <Coordinate Order="0" X="26.2" Y="280." />
                <Coordinate Order="1" X="26.2" Y="279. " />
                <Coordinate Order="2" X="26." Y="278.8" />
                .........
                .........
                .........
                <Coordinate Order="14" X="25.8" Y="280." />
                <Coordinate Order="15" X="26." Y="280.2" />
                <Coordinate Order="16" X="26.2" Y="280." />
            </Coordinates>
        </Annotation>
    </Annotations>
</ASAP_Annotations>
```

I know it may be implemented by `xml.etree.ElementTree`,but I  never learn it,could you please tell me how to do it in python.Thank you ~

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#building-xml-documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple for loop will do that:

```
headerXML = '''<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ASAP_Annotations>
    <Annotations>
        <Annotation Name="Annotation 0" Type="Spline" PartOfGroup="_1" Color="#F4FA58">
            <Coordinates>
'''

elements = ""

i = 0
for element in a:
    elements = elements+ '<Coordinate Order="%s" X="%s" Y="%s" />\n'% (i,element[0],element[1] )
    i = i + 1


footerXML = '''
            </Coordinates>
        </Annotation>
    </Annotations>
</ASAP_Annotations>
'''

XML =(headerXML+elements+footerXML)

outFile = open("coordinates.xml","w")
outFile.write(XML)
outFile.close()
```

Comment: Could you please tell me  how to write it to a xml file?

Comment: Check it again, I removed the first line which was a blank line